# Homebrew Yosemite Apache issue

Tags: php, apache, homebrew, dnsmasq

I installed a Homebrew Apache setup as explained [here](https://echo.co/blog/os-x-1010-yosemite-local-development-environment-apache-php-and-mysql-homebrew).

For me, it doesn't work at the moment. 
When running `httpd -DFOREGROUND`, I'm getting the next error:

`httpd: Syntax error on line 117 of /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.2/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.27_2/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so into server: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.27_2/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so, 10): Symbol not found: _ap_unixd_config\n Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.27_2/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so\n Expected in: /usr/local/bin/httpd\n in /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.27_2/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`.

The file (/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.27_2/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so) does exist though.

Running `dnsmasq --keep-in-foreground` then, it fails with `dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for 127.0.0.1: Address already in use`.

All error logs in troubleshooting are empty.

Important to know is, that I installed another setup earlier, before upgrading to 10.10 that did work for a while, stopped working suddenly. After that, I decided to upgrade my OS and removed everything as explained in the Troubleshooting section. I restarted from the beginning.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if it could help, but I ran brew gist-logs php55.
This is the one: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4192838c7c3372d23827

Answer (score 0):

Try to `brew reinstall php55 --homebrew-apxs`.
As mentioned [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/1229), this should solve this problem.